# Two checkboxes with same value but diffrent code (Brainteaser)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to learn some HTML and JavaScript (from mostly using C#) and I got a test from a friend in making a small webstore.

I have some checkboxes for the different items, and the goal is if I combine different products, I get a discount. However there are two items with the same value that need different combinations for discounts. But the challange is that I am **NOT ALLOWED** to edit the html file.

Is there a way to tell these items apart with JavaScript? The only thing differing is the `<h2>`.

Again, I am very new to JavaScript, but I do have some knowledge of scripting, so if you got an solution, please do comment on what the function does so I can learn it better to implement in the code.

HTML and code:
Note that this is not the whole code, this is the only parts that I think is connected to each other for this question. If full script is wished for, I will make a pastebin for it.

```js
$('body').on('click', '.fruit, .stuff1, .stuff2, .stuff3', update);

function update(){
  let fruit = $('.fruit>input:checked').val();
  fruit = parseInt(fruit);
  fruit = fruit? fruit : 0;
  
  let price = fruit + stuff1 + stuff2 + stuff3;
//If combined, get discount
//This is for the banana
//This should only apply for banana
  if(fruit == 200 && stuff1 == 100)
  {
    price = price * 0.8;
    $('#confirm').children('h2').text("You get 20% discount");
    
  }
//This is an second discount in a else if ladder
//This is for apple
//This should only apply for apple
   else if(fruit == 200 && stuff1 == 150)
  {
    price = price * 0.9;
    $('#confirm').children('h2').text("You get 10% discount");
  }
  else
  {
    $('#confirm').children('h2').text("You dident get anny discount");
  }
    $('#price').val(price);
  display(price);
}
```

```html
<div class="picker">
  <div class="fruit">
    <section>
      <h2>Banana</h2>
    </section>
    <input type="radio" name="fruit" value="200">
  </div>
  <div class="fruit">
    <section>
      <h2>Apple</h2>
    </section>
    <input type="radio" name="fruit" value="200">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Looks like plenty of JavaScript - where's the "Java"?

Comment: Is there a way to tell the banana and apple "checkboxes" apart - no, because they are radio buttons...  as they have the same name, only one will be checked.  If you want to know which it is, then it would be (from the html posted) `$("input.fruit:checked").closest("div.fruit").find("section").text()`

Comment: You need to realize one basic thing - Javascript is NOT Java. Those are 2 very different languages.

Comment: I've edited the text to remove references to "Java".  As @pbialy stated, they are not the same.

Comment: Thanks alot! Did not know there was a differance in the two. I will keep that in mind for the future!

Answer (score 1):

When you use `document.getElementsByName("fruit")` in JavaScript it returns an array; so, `document.getElementsByName("fruit")[0]` returns the first radio and `document.getElementsByName("fruit")[1]` returns the second radio.

That said, you are using jQuery which is a JavaScript Framework.  The syntax in jQuery to do the same thing is the slightly shorter `$('[name="fruit"]')`.

Comment: Haha, I used to tell everyone that too, but so many people call it a framework, at some point I just gave up.